# De CTE em SQL para álgebra relacional

Tags: sql, group-by, order-by

Como passar uma CTE em SQL para álgebra relacional, como por exemplo:

```
with publicacao_cte (nome,nr_publicacoes) 
AS 
( 
select 
candidato.nome, 
Count(1) as nr_publicacoes 
from 
candidato, 
cv, 
ficha_inscricao, 
publicacao_cv 
where 
candidato.bi = ficha_inscricao.bi and 
candidato.bi = cv.bi and 
cv.cod_cv = publicacao_cv.cod_cv 
group by candidato.nome
)
```

Também gostava de saber como se faz o `group by` e `order by` em álgebra relacional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei duas publicações no stackoverflow.com que respondem parcialmente à pergunta

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665635/algebra-relational-sql-group-by-sort-by-order-by

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613953/which-of-the-following-can-you-not-do-in-relational-algebra